# Angular2. Не передаются POST параметры на серверной

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, http, angular2

Отправляю текстовые данные на сервер таким кодом:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from  "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable() export class DemoService {

constructor(private http:Http) {
}

createFood() {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    let date = {
        id: 1,
        name: "Test"
    };

    let body = JSON.stringify(date);

    return this.http.post('http://server.com.ua/api', body, headers).map((res:Response) => res.json());
}
}
```

На сервере проверяю масив $_POST (в файл и на почту) а там "[]"  (пусто);

Comment: какая версия ангуляра?

Comment: _JSON.stringify_ можно не делать

Comment: @Grundy 2.0.0-rc.1

Comment: советую обновиться до релизной версии. Там по пути к ней было несколько breaking changes

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
> ```

Подозреваю, что эту переменную надо передавать в запрос.

Comment: кстати по идее в консоли куча ошибок должна была быть из-за неверной передачи